# Can't update an input with angular click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have this html:

```
<input type="range" value="{{kelvins}}" ng-model="temperatura" ng-change="atualizaTemperatura(temperatura)" min="3000" max="8000" step="100" name="temperatura">
<ion-list ng-repeat="temp in listTemperatura | orderBy:nome">
  <ion-item class="item-dark" style="margin-bottom: 2px">
    <span ng-click="selectTemperatura(temp)">{{temp.nome}}</span>
    <span class="pull-right" ng-click="excluiItem(temp)" style="font-size:larger"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

and this is in the controller

```
$scope.selectTemperatura = function(temp){
  $scope.kelvins = temp.temp;
  $scope.temperatura = temp.temp;
};
```

What I'm doing wrong?
I can't update the input and the label upon clicking on the item

Comment: can u provide a codepen for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track the selected temp and use its values with ng-model. Model will update the value you dont need to change it. There is your example...

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){

$scope.listTemperatura = [{temp:10, nome:"Click ME 1"}, {temp:80, nome:"Click ME 2"}]

$scope.selectTemperatura = function(temp){
  $scope.selectedTemp = angular.copy(temp);
};


})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" >
  


  
  <input type="range" ng-model="selectedTemp.temp" ng-change="atualizaTemperatura(temperatura)">
  {{selectedTemp.nome}}
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="temp in listTemperatura | orderBy:nome">
      <div class="item-dark" style="margin-bottom: 2px">
        <span ng-click="selectTemperatura(temp)">{{temp.nome}}</span>
        <span class="pull-right" ng-click="excluiItem(temp)" style="font-size:larger"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  
  
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting to happen? Is it the {{temp.nome}} in the span? If so, where do you access the 'nome' property? Your method only looks at temp.temp in both cases.

Edit: In type="range" inputs you need to set an upper limit and lower limit. So for example $scope.min and $scope.max; your method could change easily enough to:

```
// Declare these as global $scope variables:
$scope.min = 1;
$scope.max = 999;

$scope.selectTemperatura = function(type = 'min', temp) {
  $scope[type] = temp;
};
```

And your html change slightly for the click:

```
<span ng-click="selectTemperatura('min', temp)">{{temp.nome}}</span>
```

That would set the minimum value, but you could just as easily put selectTemperature('max', temp) so set the max value instead.

Your original range slider would need a minor alteration too for the min/max values:

```
<input type="range" value="{{kelvins}}" ng-model="temperatura"
  max="{{max}}" min="{{min}}" ng-change="atualizaTemperatura(temperatura)" />
```

Comment: When I click at the item (ng-click="selectTemperatura(temp)"") I need to update the value of the input range(ng-model="temperatura"). But it doesn't works

Comment: Even with min and max, the problem is applying the 'temp' in the type="range" input. I get the right value on 'temp', but '$scope.temperatura' or '$scope["temperatura"]' is undefined

Answer (score -1):

Code seems good to me , just make sure your're getting click on that element(Parent element might be above child element).